# How to pass arguments to ng-cli through nx affected:test?

Tags: angular, angular-cli, monorepo, nrwl-nx

I want to pass some arguments to `ng test` command when running affected projects (for CI purposes).
For example: `ng test --codeCoverage=true --watch=false --progress=false`.
How it can be done through `nx affected:test`?
Tried `nx affected --help`, but it doesn't contain such information.
As a naive solution i can write custom node script, execute and get result of `nx print-affected`  and then run commands from this result, but I want to find more efficient way.

Comment: @vsavkin help us ples

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found out that `nx-cli` redirects all unknown parameters to `ng-cli`.
So it can be done like:  `nx affected:test --codeCoverage --watch=false --progress=false`.
UPD:
I can't find it in the docs, but running `nx serve` will throw message like:
[image: NX NOTE]